# Changing code font size on wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, fonts

In a post of mine in wordpress I'm posting source code as described [here](https://en.support.wordpress.com/code/posting-source-code/).

An example of the code goes like this:

```
[code language="csharp"]
   // Code goes here
[/code]
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

What I want to do is change the font size and make it smaller.

I've inspected the element of the code which gives the following:

[image]

I've tried adding custom css using the Simple Custom CSS plugin to change the font size but to no avail. 
The CSS that I've tried is the following:

```
code {
    font-size: 10px;
}

.csharp plain {
    font-size: 10px;
}

.csharp keyword {
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

How can I change the font-size of the code?

Answer (score 1):

Your element seems to be part of the page therefore custom CSS should work. Most probably it is not working as the CSS rules of another stylesheet (probably the WordPress.com default) are stronger or more specific.

Try with the CSS !important rule:

```
code {
    font-size: 10px !important;
}

.csharp plain {
    font-size: 10px !important;
}

.csharp keyword {
    font-size: 10px !important;
}
```

If this still does not work use more specific CSS selectors with the important rule.

If this still does not work your custom stylesheet is not applied yet and you have to check your configuration.

Comment: Unfortunately this hasn't worked. What do you mean by more specific CSS selectors?

Comment: More specific would be e.g. .syntaxhighlighter code.plain { font-size:10px !important; }

However most likely your stylesheet does not apply to the code. Check why!

Comment: Only just started with css and html, so don't have much of an idea how things are working behind wordpress. I'm trying my best however :)

Comment: Great! It worked with more specific selectors, add them to your answer and I'll accept. I added the following: `code.plain`, `code.keyword`, `code.string`, `code.color1` all with `.syntaxhighlighter` prefix and with the `important!` keyword

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to style elements based on their css classes, but your code doesn't have the "." before their names. Based on the example of the link:

```
.syntaxhighlighter { font-size: 10px; }
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Even with !important, @kyriacos_k?

Comment: Yes even with `!important`

Answer (score 0):

Changing the font size of your code on WordPress is pretty easy. This is what you need to do.

**1. Switch from the `Visual` tab to the `html` tab in the editor**

[image]

**2. Surround your codes with these tags:**
     `<pre><code><span style="font-size: small;"> YOUR CODE GOES HERE</span></code></pre>`

for example:

[image]

**That's it.**

This was what my code looked like in preview mode **BEFORE** I used those tags (While I used `[language= "java"]`)

[image]

And this is what it looks like **AFTER** using the tags:

[image]

The available font sizes are `xx-small, x-small, small, medium, large, x-large, xx-large.`

If you are not familiar with `html`, it is advisable to switch back to the visual tab. Hope this was helpful